# Python - strptime ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I believe I am missing something trivial. After reading all the questions about `strptime ValueError` yet I feel the format seems right, Here is the below error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loadScrip.py", line 18, in <module>
    nextDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '20l2/08/25' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

I am using Python 2.6.6 under Linux x86_64. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error indicates you have data with the letter `l` (lowercase L) instead of the number `1` in the year:

```
ValueError: time data '20l2/08/25' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

That is not a valid date that'll fit the requested format; replacing the `l` with `1` and the input date works just fine:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20l2/08/25', "%Y/%m/%d")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '20l2/08/25' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2012/08/25', "%Y/%m/%d")
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 25, 0, 0)
```

Fix your input, the format is correct.

Comment: @Martjin : Great answer, one question please, how can I read a date format from a file as datetime, I mean I have a date 2016-06-21 and I want to read it as 2016-06-21 00:00:00 because the format could be date or datetime and I should read it as datetime always. Thanks.

Comment: @JadChahine: exactly as described here; use `datetime.strptime()` on those strings.

Comment: yes but if the string is a datetime and I use %Y/%m/%d then I got a error that the time date does not match the format.

Comment: Well, then you have a string that can't be parsed by that specific format string. Make sure you have strings that do match, or adjust your format string. This includes newline characters or other whitespace, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it with the string variable:

```
>>> start_day = 2015188
>>> print start_day
2015188
>>> print conv
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=188, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> conv = time.strptime( str(start_day), "%Y%j" )
>>> print conv
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=188, tm_isdst=-1)
```

For whatever reason, you have to put the string variable inside the str() thing and all the examples I have found online only show the date in quotes.

Comment: You need `str` in your case because you're *starting with an integer* - this doesn't solve the OP's problem